# How multi-types containers (array/vector/list) are traditionally implemented in C++? (without Tuple of course)

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, tuples

I'm curious to know that how multi-types containers, such Array or Vector or List are implemented in C++? I mean putting integers, strings and/or vectors/arrays inside one array/vector.

You might ask me what is the case that requires such usage?

My Answer: Assume that I have an XML which holds the information about students like this:

```
<school tag='town'>
 <student>
      <name>Robert Largen</name>
      <number>87854788</number>
 </student>
 <student>
      <name>Robert Largen</name>
      <number>87854788</number>
 </student>
 <student>
      <name>Robert Largen</name>
      <number>87854788</number>
 </student>
</school>
```

I process the XML, and well, I get the numbers as a sequence of characters, but then I want to cast integer as their types immediately right after retrieval and put them into a multi-type container which I don't know how to accomplish yet. The above is not a real case of an existing project.

Problem: I like to know how were problems like this tackled traditionally in C++? Has Boost been a super standard to be used? Or c++ with its `tuple` has really saved the world of C++ programmers? I'm confused really.

Comment: What do you mean by "multi-type container?"

Comment: I updated the question. I mean putting int, string or another array/vector inside one container (array/vector)

Comment: I see. I think you refer to a *variant* data type, not a tuple. A `tuple<int, string>` for example would hold an `int` *and* a `string`, while a `variant<int, string>` would hold an `int` *or* a `string`.

Comment: No I mean a multi-types, like tuple, not variant

Comment: That doesn't agree with the text of your question. Can you post a concrete diagram of this theoretical list structure and a sample of the kind of contents it might contain? Your question is vague at best and self-contradictory at worst.

Comment: It sounds like you are confused about how a particular data structure is implemented. Could you explicitly name that data type? Is it `std::vector<int>`, or `std::tuple<int, double>`, or `boost::variant<int, double>`?

Answer (score 2):

If by "multy-type container" you mean a container that holds a set of different types, then it can be implemented in many ways. For example you can use a container of `boost::variant`s (with the visitor pattern) or `boost::any`s or create a polymorphic container with a common base interface. It really depends on how this container is then used.

If you mean: an object that holds a predetermined set of subobjects of specific types (like `stundent` there), then you can simply use a POD or a `struct`/`class`.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular case you just nedd a

```
struct student
{
    std::string name;
    unsigned long number;
};

struct school
{
    std::string tag;
    std::vector<student> students;
};
```

And eventually a packing class the envelope all this providing proper accessors and manipulators.

This is true wherever the XML structure is fixed.

If you want to read a generic XML (where tags, properties and values can literally be anything), you can represent a simple XML tree as

```
struct node
{
    std::string tagname;
    std::map<std::string,std::string> properties;
    std::string value;
    std::vector<node> children;
};
```

where everything is just ... text.

There can be many other ways, but this -given the example you gave- risk to be too broad.

Answer (score 1):

If you`re asking for a replacement for a tuple, you can just go with structs. E.g.:

```
struct Student{
     int id;
     string name;
};
```

Some template meta programming aside, I don't know any context, where you couldn't use a struct in place of a tuple. The only drawback is, that you have to define the struct up front, whereas the tuple (its members) is usually defined ad hoc, at the site of the variable or parameter definition (both has to happen at compiletime of course).